# Why do I get "invalid format character" when loading this on Android?

Tags: android

I'm trying to load this on Emacs on Android.

```
  (defvar bootstrap-version)
  (setq straight-repository-branch "develop") ; Need this for new org-contrib location
  (let ((bootstrap-file
     (expand-file-name "straight/repos/straight.el/bootstrap.el" user-emacs-directory))
    (bootstrap-version 5))
    (unless (file-exists-p bootstrap-file)
      (with-current-buffer
    (url-retrieve-synchronously
     "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/raxod502/straight.el/develop/install.el"
     'silent 'inhibit-cookies)
    (goto-char (point-max))
    (eval-print-last-sexp)))
    (load bootstrap-file nil 'nomessage))
  (straight-use-package 'use-package)
```

, but I get:

```
error: invalid format character: `%t`
```

Not really sure how to debug this;)

EDIT: Found this bug, so I guess it's not supported on Android https://github.com/radian-software/straight.el/issues/1118

Comment: `(setq debug-on-error t)`, then show the backtrace.

Comment: Presumably, it happens when the bootstrap file is loaded, so the error in the backtrace you will produce after toggling `debug-on-error` as @Drew recommends, will point to some place in that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

straight.el is not supported for the native port of Emacs for Android.

I have found some references to Emacs GUI being launched from termux, where it indeed does work, but I haven't dug into that yet.